# Can an Android app have exclusive access to the audio h/w?

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to build an application that will alert the user in case of an emergency by playing an audio file. To override situations where the user may be playing loud music and the emergency announcement may not be heard by the user (due to sharing of audio h/w with multiple apps), can I get exclusive access to audio output so only my audio stream is audible and rest all are stopped/killed/muted?

Comment: Perhaps you can somehow change the notification sound and fire a notification?

Comment: Will it really mute all other sound sources? Plus, the emergency announcement may run into minutes, can you really play that long a Notification sound. What happens if the user clicks on the Notification, Android will most likely stop the Notification sound immediately. This does not seem to be an ideal solution. Is there no other solution?

Comment: I'm not an Android programmer so I can't answer all of those questions for you, but on any Android device I've used, the notification sound does stop all other sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AudioManager to set your audio source to 'solo' which will mute other audio streams [setStreamSolo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamSolo%28int,%20boolean%29) or you can individually mute other streams using [setStreamMute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute%28int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: setStreamSolo() will have no effect if isVolumeFixed() returns true, added in API 21, but will work if it returns false.